# Calling the destructor from a different method of the same class

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a problem

```
class Polygon 
{
    private:
        Vertex* vertices;
        int numVerts;
        static int RefCount;

    public:
        //Constructors
        Polygon(Vertex vert[], int numVerts){
            vertices = vert;
            this->numVerts = numVerts;
        }
        Polygon() {
            vertices = 0;
            numVerts = 0;
        }
        ~Polygon() {

        }
        ReleasePolygon()
        {
            if (RefCount == 0)
                delete this; // <-------- is this line ok?
            else
                RefCount--;
        }
}
```

Is this a proper way of calling the destructor at this point?

Comment: Let the destructor do the deleting and don't call it explicitly. A release method should only decrease the reference count.

Comment: I don't think there is necessarily anything wrong about calling `delete` from within a release-method, but what confuses me is that your reference count is `static`. Why is that?

Comment: This seems to be written in a C++ derivative.

Comment: @Zacrath Why do you say that?

Comment: How do you know it was created dynamically? What if it's on the stack?

Comment: @Dukeling Because functions need to have a return type and static members need to be referenced with the scope operator (`::`)

Comment: @Zacrath Using `::` for static members [does not appear to be required](https://ideone.com/Oq9juA). And I wouldn't be too surprised if some compilers allow no return type, even if it's not proper C++ / consistent with the spec (?).

Comment: this is a duplicate of C++: Delete this? only thq for u r comments :)